# How to configure mail server to report a hostname distinct from server name

Tags: email, mta

I have a VPS set up with Ubuntu 10.04 *Lucid* running exim4 as the MTA.  The machine name itself is something easily recognizable to us (in this case, 'Fermat'), but the machine itself is responsible for serving up one of our domains (i.e. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)).

When generating an email from exim, the email headers are reporting the server name (Fermat) instead of the domain name (example.com).

Is there a way to 'force' exim to report the server name as example.com without changing the machine's host name?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the content of **`/etc/mailname`** is `example.com`. If not, change it and reboot:

```
sudo nano /etc/mailname
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 4):

Reconfigure exim4:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4
```

One of the questions it'll ask you is for the "System mail name". You want to change that.

Comment: I did this part and even set it to 'example.com'.  In the email headers, though, it still shows:
`Received: from Fermat (mail.example.com [11.22.33.44])`